# weird block check after a reindex

Tags: bitcoind, full-node, reindex

is it normal that after a reindex the block check restarts strangely fast up to a certain point? My node was already synced.
[image]

The GIF is not speeded up. It's the real speed of the sync...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks normal. Reindexing essentially means deleting the block index and the chainstate databases. The result is that blocks will be read from disk and re-verified and the databases rebuilt. With many blocks, this can go quite quickly since the blocks are relatively easy to verify, some checks may be skipped, and blocks don't need to be downloaded over the network.

Comment: This is especially true for the first ~100,000 blocks which are mostly empty.

Comment: Thank you so much.